# How to save my html5 application progress?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote an application for my friend who works in a car showroom. He wanted some sort of program to keep track of the cars coming in and out with their details and stuff using tables like excel so I did just that using JavaScript.

The thing is everytime you close or refresh the browser all of the tables inserted are gone obviously. What do I do and what do I use to make everything stay the same whenever he reopens the application locally?

Is it cookies or HTML5 application cache or what exactly I've looked everywhere and haven't found an answer. I don't have any server or database which I can use.

Comment: you have a few options for storage with HTML5: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: The decent thing to do would be to use a database (which requires server side code to interact with). The simplest short term solution is to use [html5 localstorage](https://www.google.nl/search?q=html5+localstorage&oq=html5+localstorage&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.639j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Here's a snippet to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/Hn7jc/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following:

1. [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/)
2. [LocalStorage API](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) (no polyfills)
3. [IndexDB + Localstorage: localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage)
4. [Hood.ie](http://hood.ie/)
5. [jQuery Store](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-store)
6. [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js)

There are so many other ways to store data (cookies, WebSQL, etc.) that it's really a matter of preference; each method has its advantages and disadvantages.  For example, if you're storing only small amounts of data and need cross-browser compatibility, cookies are probably the best option; conversely, if you are storing large amounts of data, such that you may exceed the 20MB limit, then IndexDB or one of the polyfill libraries above will be a good fit (note that most of them avoid the 20MB limit through clever "hacks").

Comment: You can do it with just a few lines of code, why would you use a library for it? jQuery-store literally tells you not to use it any more when you check the readme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage object.

The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

```
 // Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
var userLastName = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```